# Error in installing angular-bootstrap-affix using bower

Tags: angularjs, bower, angular-strap, angular-bootstrap

I am using this command to install mgcrea's angular-bootstrap-affix using bower :

```
bower install angular-bootstrap-affix --save
```

But it is showing the following error:

> ECMDERR Failed to execute
>
> `"git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/mgcrea/angular-bootstrap-affix.git"`,
>
> exit code of #128

Can anybody let me know how I can resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the repository mentioned above no longer exists.
You can use this fork here: https://github.com/passy/angular-bootstrap-affix.git

Use "angular-bootstrap-affix": "https://github.com/passy/angular-bootstrap-affix.git" in bower.json

Or create your own fork from it and give that URL.